# Merging K Sorted Lists attempt

Tags: c++, c

Ive recently received a hw that asks me to merge k sorted linked lists. The idea sugested by the teacher was to store those lists in a heap, and simply use heapify. However, im having a horible time dealing with pointers and structurs. Here is my code, I would appreciate any recommendations, hyperlinks, or corrections because im kind of stuck.
At first I need a bit of help with functions: createRandomList, createHeap, and only then the proper merge.
PS: FillRandomArray is a function designed by my teacher to fill arrays randomly, so it shouldn`t be a source of errors. 
Thanksguys!

```
    typedef struct node {
        int val;
        struct node * next;
    };

    typedef struct list{
        node *head;
    };

    list* createRandomList(int size) {
        int *arr;
        arr = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        list* myList = (list*)malloc(size * sizeof(list));
        FillRandomArray(arr, size, 10, 500, false, 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            myList->head->val = arr[i];
            cout << arr[i] << " next ";
            if(i != size - 1)
                myList->head = myList->head->next;
        }
        return myList;
    }

    list** createHeap(int k,int size) {
        list* myList = (list*)malloc(size * sizeof(list));
        list **heap = (list**)malloc(k * size * sizeof(list));
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            cout << i;
            heap[i] = createRandomList(size);
        }
        return heap;
    }

    void heapify(list** heap, int i, int size) {

    }

    list** buildHeap(list **heap, int k) {

    }

    bool checkHeap(list** heap, int k) {
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            if (heap[i]->head == NULL)
                return false;
            else return true;
        }
    }

    int* mergeSort(list** heap, int n, int k) {
        int *sorted;
        int i = 0;
        sorted = (int*)malloc(n * k * sizeof(int));
        list** minHeap = buildHeap(heap, k);
        while (k > 0) {
            if (checkHeap(minHeap, k) == TRUE) {
                sorted[i] = minHeap[0]->head->val;
                minHeap[0]->head = minHeap[0]->head->next;
                i++;
            }
            else {
                for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                    if (minHeap[j]->head == NULL) {
                        k--;
                        delete(minHeap[k]);
                        for (int m = j; m < k; m++)
                            minHeap[m] = minHeap[m + 1];
                    }
                }
            }
            minHeap = buildHeap(minHeap, k);
        }
        return sorted;
    } 

    void main(){
        int n, k;
        cout << "Please enter the number of lists that you wish to have: ";
        cin >> k;
        cout << "\nNow please enter the number of elements that you wish your list to posses: ";
        cin >> n;
        cout << "\nThe lists to be merged are: ";
        list **heap = (list**)malloc(k * n * sizeof(list));

        heap = createHeap(k, n);

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                cout << heap[i]->head->val<<" ";
                heap[i]->head = heap[i]->head->next;
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Merge sort would be much simpler...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your issue is that you're not really understanding how to use lists.

The line of code `list* myList = (list*)malloc(size * sizeof(list));` allocates space for `size` lists elements (or rather it returns a pointer to an array of `size` lists) rather than a list that can contain `size` elements.

If you want to allocate a list of `size` elements you can use the following code.

```
list* listFromArray(int* a, size_t size) {
  list* l = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
  l->head = NULL;
  node* current;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    current = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    current->next = l->head;
    current->val = a[size - i - 1];
    l->head = current;
  }
}
```

How does the code work?

1. First we initialize a list with malloc (note we just request for the
   size of a single list).
2. We loop over each element in the array
3. We initialize a node for each element

Note: We start from the back of the list so that we can just push new nodes onto the front (both ways are possible but the forward direction requires an additional pointer).

You have a similar problem for the `createHeap` function.

```
list** createHeap(int k,int size) {
    list **heap = (list**)malloc(k * sizeof(*list)); // create array of k list pointers
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        cout << i;
        heap[i] = createRandomList(size); // populate ith entry with a random list
    }
    heapify(heap, k / 2, k); // turn unsorted array of lists into a heap of lists
    return heap;
}
```

Since you don't have any specification of heapify, I assume your function will take an unsorted array of lists, an index `i` (with the invariant that all lists after i are in heap order) and `size` the size of the heap and ensure the array is in heap order.

For heapify, you might want to look at what the function should do:
https://medium.com/basecs/heapify-all-the-things-with-heap-sort-55ee1c93af82

The main idea is as I said to start from the halfway point and ensure the array is in heap order (we know all heaps of size 1 are heaps so we can start at 1/2 way point). Then we go from there to the beginning of the array and "sink" the top of the heap rooted at position `i` to it's correct position. Note: the children of an element at position `i` is `2 * i + 1` and `2 * (i + 1)`.

You should consider what you want `checkHeap` to do. I think this should be what it means to be a (min)heap of lists. Right now you just check to see if the heap has no empty lists. I would argue an array of empty lists is in heap order. And that the order of lists should be lexographical (ordered by first element, then second, etc) with the special case of the empty list being the supremum (largest element).

Assuming heapify works as described above, and you have a function `node* pick(list** heap)` that picks the lowest node in the heap and removes it from the heap then merge becomes much simpler.

```
int* merge(list** heap, int n, int k) {
    int* sorted;
    node* low;

    sorted = (int*)malloc(k * n * sizeof(int));

    int i = 0;
    while ((low = pick(heap)) != NULL) {
        heapify(heap, 0, k);
        sorted[i++] = low->val;
        free(low);
    }
    return sorted;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. However i have a few further questions.

Comment: 1.     heapify(heap, k / 2, k); // turn unsorted array of lists into a heap of lists

Comment: This is my heapify:

Comment: In my heapify, i receive as a parameter a heap, then i save in another array the value of each list head in the heap. I use that to heapify, as i`m more comfortable using arrays. The thing is that the function that i usualy use to build a heap is: 'for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)  heapify(a, i, n);'. Why would it work if I call heapify(a, k/2,k). My heapify is exactly like the one recommended by you, just that I have implemented it recursively. Thank you, im looking forward to your response!